# CORB job using ModuleExecutor set up

Tags: xquery, marklogic-corb

I have simple search query on CORB job. I am following https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki/ModuleExecutor-Tool for the set up that looks for one xqy file (PROCESS-MODULE). I don't have any issue on regular CORB job but with this set up I am getting

> com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.XccConfigException: Unrecognized connection scheme: null

Can somebody please help me figure out why?

The regular corb job is working and is fully functional but when I use https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki/ModuleExecutor-Tool approach I am getting this XCC exception and I can't figured out why.

Comment: How are you setting the XCC connection URI? Can you post the command to invoke the job if passing on the commandline or show the options file (obviously obscure sensitive info)? What version of CORB and XCC jars are you running?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the XCC connection string is malformed, or you haven't set the XCC connection URI at all. The XCC connection string should start with the "xcc://" scheme.

The [**XCC-CONNECTION-URI**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#XCC-CONNECTION-URI) can be passed on the commandline as the first argument to the ModuleExecutor Main method:

```
java -cp marklogic-corb-2.4.1.jar:marklogic-xcc-9.0.8.jar -DOPTIONS-FILE=job.options \
  com.marklogic.developer.corb.ModuleExecutor xcc://user:password@localhost:8123
```

Or the property can be set in the options file:

```
XCC-CONNECTION-URI=xcc://user:password@localhost:8123
```

Or it can be set as a system property:

```
-DXCC-CONNECTION-URI=xcc://user:password@localhost:8123
```